# Mapping a map of two abstract entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to Map the following data structure in hibernate:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=Array(CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST))
  @JoinTable(name = "links", joinColumns = Array(new JoinColumn(name = "link_id")))
  @MapKey(name="id")
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  def getLinksMapNative:java.util.Map[MyClass,MyClass] = {
    linksMap
  }
```

I have the following problem though:

- If I leave the MapKey annotation, when loading from the session, the Key of the Map is the integer id of MyClass instead of being an instance of MyClass and this result into a ClassCastException at runtime
- If I take it off, since MyClass is an abstract entity I get:

  org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface

at the moment of persisting.

Can one map a Map of two abstract entities in Hibernate, and if yes, how?